# Save selected row on bootstrap-table

Tags: jquery, row, bootstrap-table

I Have a problem with bootstrap-table

I need my bootstrap-table to remember options of the table and selected row because when I refresh the page I want the same options,
I want the table reselects the same row, the same page of the las selection.
Is there a way to save the table status?

```html
<div class="tab-content">
<div class="tab-pane active" id="idContatti">
   <div class="table-responsive" ">
      <!--data-pagination="true"-->
      <table id="tableConttatti" data-state-save="true" data-state-save-id-table="save" data-height="500" data-id-field="Codice" data-click-to-select="true" data-show-pagination-switch="true" data-pagination="true" data-search="true" data-row-style="rowStyle">
         <thead>
            <tr>
               <th data-field="state" data-radio="true"></th>
               <th data-field="__rank" data-sortable="true" data-halign="center" data-align="center">N.</th>
               <th data-field="societa" data-sortable="true" data-halign="center" data-align="center">societa</th>
               <th data-field="partitaIva" data-sortable="true" data-halign="center" data-align="center">P.Iva</th>
               <th data-field="codiceFiscale" data-sortable="true" data-halign="center" data-align="center">Codice Fiscale</th>
               <th data-field="indirizzo"data-sortable="true" data-halign="center" data-align="center">indirizzo</th>
               <th data-field="citta" data-sortable="true" data-halign="center" data-align="center">citta</th>
               <th data-field="telefono1" data-sortable="true" data-halign="center" data-align="center">telefono1</th>
               <th data-field="cellulare" data-sortable="true" data-halign="center" data-align="center">cellulare</th>
               <th data-field="fax" data-sortable="true" data-halign="center" data-align="center">fax</th>
               <th data-field="email" data-sortable="true" data-halign="center" data-align="center">email</th>
            </tr>
         </thead>
      </table>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: HTML is stateless. That means when you refresh the page any form data or item selection is lost. You have to make use of a programming language such as JavaScript to save any kind of data you want to preserve.

Comment: I used javascript and jquery in my project obviously...how to save my stasus?

Comment: i tried to save state with this method:

$("#btn_opt").click(function() {
    var nR = tableConttatti.bootstrapTable('getSelections')[0];
    var options = tableConttatti.bootstrapTable('getOptions');

    var row = sessionStorage.setItem('row', nR);
    var opzioni = sessionStorage.setItem('opzioni', options);
    console.log("riga:", sessionStorage.getItem("row"));
    console.log("options:", sessionStorage.getItem("opzioni"));

})

but the result of log is ([object object]
how to take the data of object?

Comment: Please include all _your_ JavaScript in your question. Properly formatted so its clear and readable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$("#tableConttatti").click(function(id, row, index) {

```
var nR = tableConttatti.bootstrapTable('getSelections')[0];
        var options = tableConttatti.bootstrapTable('getOptions');
        console.log("pagina=", options.pageNumber);
        console.log("lunghezza=", options.pageSize);

        var riga = localStorage.setItem("row", nR.__rank);
        var pagina = localStorage.setItem("page", options.pageNumber);
        var lunghezza = localStorage.setItem("length", options.pageSize);
        return true;
```

}

$(document).ready(function() {

```
tableConttatti.bootstrapTable({
    url: "_elabPost.php?Inst=GETCONTATTI",
    pageSize: localStorage.getItem("length"),
    pageNumber: localStorage.getItem("page"),
    onLoadSuccess: function() {
        getSelectedRow()
    }


});
```

function getSelectedRow() {

```
var riga_sel = localStorage.getItem("row");
console.log("riga_sel", riga_sel);
var tr = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");
var td = document.getElementsByClassName("td");
for (var i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    if (tr[i].cells[1].innerText == riga_sel) {
        console.log(tr[i]);
        $(tr[i]).addClass("selected");
        return;
    }
}
```

}